# можно ли гугл таблицах записать макрос с использованием правка->найти и заменить

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

собственно выгружаю данные в гугл таблицу, дробные значения чисел выгружаются с разными разделителями дробной части ("," или ".")

хочу найти все значения с разделителем "." и заменить их на ","

для этого выделяю столбец, далее правка → найти и заменить https://yadi.sk/i/5gODIB-DKU6c7w

решил записать макрос, но тАкое действие просто не записывается..
это вообще возможно? если в макрос такое не записать, то как быть?

Comment: Вы можете добиться этого, считывая скриптом все значения на листе (как массив), перебирая массив, заменяя значения, а затем записывая весь массив обратно на лист.

Comment: я подобрал вот такую функцию =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(F1:F;"[.]";",");F1:F)));COUNTA(F1:F);1)

т.к. google script -ом не владею, пытаюсь реализовать что нужно с помощью записи макроса,
последовательность следующая: создаю колонку справа от текущей (с данными), испольую формулу выше, копирую значения массив полученных значений в третью колонку, удаляю две первых, но после исполнения тАкого макроса - получаю пустую колонку..

Answer (score 0):

Используйте этот код:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var new_data = data.map(row =>
    row.map(cell =>
        cell.toString().replace(/\./g, ',')
    )
);
  Logger.log(new_data);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, new_data.length, new_data[0].length).setValues(new_data);
}
```

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
  возвращает диапазон с данными.
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
  возвращает значения из этого диапазона.
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива. Здесь 2 вложенных map(): первый перебирает строки, а второй - элементы в строке.
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
  заменяет точку на запятую.
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
  записывает новый массив на лист.